# gdb backtrace with no user input?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, gdb

I'm wondering if it's possible to launch an application via GDB, on a SegFault write the backtrace to a file (to look at later), and then exit GDB all without any user input.

I'm running an application from a shell script in an infinite loop (so if it crashes it reloads) on OS boot from a non-interactive session. The application is crashing in a non-reproducible way so I need a backtrace from the crash to debug the issue. Ideally, I'd just modify the shell script to include the GDB debugging + backtracing functionality and preserve the automatic restarting of the application following a crash.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4039/print-stack-trace-of-a-core-file-without-needing-to-enter-gdb-interactively

Comment: Can you not enable core files on your system and get the backtrace that way? It seems a lot easier than a gdb loop.

Comment: `so I need a backtrace from the crash to debug the issue.` - I have not found an answer why you cannot analyze a core file from a crash? Is it because it is quite big?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thanks to Aditya Kumar; acceptable solution:

```
gdb -batch -ex "run" -ex "bt" ${my_program} 2>&1 | grep -v ^"No stack."$
```

If the program needs arguments:

```
gdb -batch -ex "run" -ex "bt" --args ${my_program} param1 param2 \
                              param3 ... 2>&1 | grep -v ^"No stack."$
```

Comment: you may want to add `--args` before `${my_program}` if `${my_program}` takes arguments

Answer (score 3):

```
gdb --batch -q <debuged_executable> <core_file> -ex bt
```

Comment: This needs `-ex run` too. Also, `-q` is not necessary with `-batch`. From `man dgb`, section `-q`: *»These messages are also suppressed in batch mode.«*

Answer (score 2):

This works with gdb 7.6:

My test program that causes a core dump if it is given a command line parameter:

```
int a(int argc)
{
  if (argc > 1) {
    int *p = 0;
    *p = *p +1;
    return  *p;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int b(int argc)
{
  return a(argc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int res = b(argc);
  return res;
}
```

My python script my_check.py:

```
def my_signal_handler (event):
  if (isinstance(event, gdb.SignalEvent)):
    log_file_name = "a.out.crash." + str(gdb.selected_inferior().pid) + ".log"
    gdb.execute("set logging file " + log_file_name )
    gdb.execute("set logging on")
    gdb.execute("set logging redirect on")
    gdb.execute("thread apply all bt")
    gdb.execute("q")

gdb.events.stop.connect(my_signal_handler)
gdb.execute("set confirm off")
gdb.execute("set pagination off")
gdb.execute("r")
gdb.execute("q")
```

So, first I run a.out and there is no crash. No log files are created:

> gdb -q -x my_check.py --args ./a.out  >/dev/null

Next I run a.out and give it one parameter:

```
>gdb -q -x my_check.py --args ./a.out 1 >/dev/null
```

And this is a crash report:

```
>cat a.out.crash.13554.log

Thread 1 (process 13554):
#0  0x0000000000400555 in a (argc=2) at main.cpp:5
#1  0x000000000040058a in b (argc=2) at main.cpp:15
#2  0x00000000004005a3 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe198) at main.cpp:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to just storing the backtrace, you could put `ulimit -c unlimited` in front of your infinite loop in your shell script. The result will be that every time your program segfaults, it will write a core dump into a file which on my system is just called `core` but on other systems might include the process id. If the program segfaults (you see this from its exit status being equal to 139) then just move the `core` file to a safe location using a unique name (for example using timestamps). With these core files and gdb you can then do even more than just look at the backtrace. Thus I guess using them might even be more useful to you.